# Enviar e Receber dados via Socket

Tags: c++, socket

Sou iniciante em socket, gostaria de saber qual é a melhor maneira de se enviar 
e receber dados. Gostaria de uma melhor explicação sobre como funciona.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(Baseado nos dados da [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com))

**send** function

- A função **send** envia dados para um socket conectado.

  **int send(
  *In*       SOCKET s,
  *In* const char   *buf,
  *In*       int    len,
  *In*       int    flags
  );**

**s**[in]
Um descritor de identificação para o socket conectado

**buf**[in]
Um ponteiro para o buffer contendo os dados a serem transmitidos

**len**[in]
O Comprimento, em bytes, dos dados contidos em buffer apontado pelo parâmetro **buf**

**flags**[in]
Especifica a maneira em que a chamada e efetuada.

**Return Value:**
Se não ocorrer erro, a função send retorna o número total de bytes enviados.
Caso contrário, um valor de SOCKET_ERROR é retornado, o código de erro
pode ser recuperado chamando WSAGetLastError.

**Exemplo:**

```
int iResult = send( ConnectSocket, sendbuf, (int)strlen(sendbuf), 0 );
    if (iResult == SOCKET_ERROR) 
    {
            wprintf(L"Send Falhou, codigo de erro %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
            closesocket(ConnectSocket);
            WSACleanup();
            return 1;
     }
```

**recv** function

- A função **recv** recebe dados de um socket conectado ou um soquete sem conexão vinculada

**int recv(
  *In*  SOCKET s,
  *Out* char   *buf,
  *In*  int    len,
  *In*  int    flags
);**

**s**[in]
Um descritor de identificação para o socket conectado

**buf**[out]
    Um ponteiro para o buffer para receber os dados de entrada.

**len**[in]
O Comprimento, em bytes, dos dados contidos em buffer apontado pelo parâmetro buf

**flags**[in]
Um conjunto de sinalizadores que influencia o comportamento desta função.

**Return Value:**

Se não houver erro a função recv retorna o número de bytes recebidos e o buffer
apontado para o parametro buf conterá os dados recebidos.
Se a conexão foi encerrada normalmente, o valor de retorno é zero.

Caso contrário, um valor de SOCKET_ERROR é retornado, o código de erro
pode ser recuperado chamando WSAGetLastError.

**Exemplo:**

```
int iResult = recv(ConnectSocket, recvbuf, recvbuflen, 0);
        if ( iResult > 0 )
            printf("Bytes Recebidos: %d\n", iResult);
        else if ( iResult == 0 )
            printf("Conexao encerrada.\n");
        else
            printf("recv falhou, codigo de erro: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
```